# Replace cell values efficiently in Dataframe based on another column data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am currently running a for loop and if statement to check and replace values in cell based on row value of another column.

Simply put, my dataframe is 9000x27 rows similar to

[image]

I am using the below code to compare first 6 digits (CONT-1) of Package column with first 6 digits of Status column and if its true take entire row information to new dataframe, if not replace status column value with NaN.

```
new_dr = pd.DataFrame(columns = pr_compliant.columns)
for index, row in pr_compliant.iterrows():
    col1 = row['Package ID'][:6]
    col2 = row['Status ID'][:6]
    if col1 == col2:
        new_dr = new_dr._append(row, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        row['Status ID'] = np.nan
        new_dr = new_dr._append(row, ignore_index=True)
new_dr = new_dr.drop_duplicates()
print(new_dr)
```

Here pr_compliant is source dataframe and new_dr is output dataframe. I want output as below

[image]

Currently its taking more than 30 secs to compare 9000 rows and push output. I am looking for efficient way to reduce the time as my master file that I am deploying this code will be 100000x27 dataframe.

Any thoughts for efficieny?

Comment: [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
pr_compliant['Status ID'] = ((pr_compliant['Status ID'].str[:6] == pr_compliant['Package ID'].str[:6])
               *pr_compliant['Status ID']).replace({'': np.nan})
```

This is kind of a slick one liner, so I'll break it down. Adding `.str` to a dataframe column lets us treat it like a string, so `pr_compliant['Status ID'].str[:6]` will give us a column of just the first 6 characters of each entry. The when we do the comparison

```
pr_compliant['Status ID'].str[:6] == pr_compliant['Package ID'].str[:6]
```

That gives us a column of True and False values, with the Trues indicating the rows where the first 6 characters match. When we mulitply that by the original `pr_compliant['Status ID']` column, that will put the status ID where the Trues are, and blank strings where the Falses are. Finally we replace those blank strings with nans using `.replace({'': np.nan})`.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you are looking for:

```py
new_dr = pr_compliant.copy()
new_dr.loc[
    new_dr["Status ID"].str[:6] != new_dr["Package ID"].str[:6],
    "Status ID",
] = np.nan
```

First we create a copy of the pr_compliant DataFrame.

Then, we use `.loc` to select the relevant rows i.e., those where the first 6 characters of "Status ID" are different from the first 6 characters of "Package ID" (`new_dr['Status ID'].str[:6] != new_dr['Package ID'].str[:6]`).
Here we use the `.str` function to be able to slice the values in both Series.

We then replace the selected rows in column 'Status ID' with np.nan.

Docs on `.loc`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html